# Get-ADGroup Hangs When Retrieving Data From Another Domain

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a PowerShell script to retrieve all AD groups and put it in a table. This script needs to run on a server that is under a different domain than the domain I want to retrieve groups from. To combat this, I added code to identify the nearest DC and pass that into the `Server` parameter for `Get-ADGroups`:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$DC = Get-ADDomainController -DomainName domain_name -Discover -NextClosestSite

$Groups = (Get-AdGroup -Server $DC.HostName[0] -Properties name, samaccountname, distinguishedname, sAMAccounttype, description, GroupType, GroupCategory, Info, Instancetype,  
                                   dSCorePropagationData,UsnCreated, UsnChanged, WhenCreated, whenchanged, ManagedBy -filter * )        

$Table = @()

$Record = @{
  "GroupName" = ""
  "sAmaccountName" = ""
  "DistinguishedName" = ""
  "sAMAccountType" = ""
  "Description" = ""
  "GroupType" = ""
  "GroupCategory" = ""
  "Info" = ""
  "InstanceType" = ""
  "dSCorePropagationData" = ""
  "UsnCreated" = ""
  "UsnChanged" = ""
  "WhenCreated" = ""
  "WhenChanged" = ""
  "ManagedBy" = ""
}
 
Foreach ($Group in $Groups) {             
           
    $Record."GroupName" = $Group.name            
    $Record."sAmaccountName" = $group.samaccountname
    $Record."DistinguishedName" = $group.distinguishedName
    $Record."sAMAccountType" = $group.sAMAccountType
    $Record."Description" = $group.description
    $Record."GroupType" = $group.grouptype
    $Record."GroupCategory" = $group.GroupCategory
    $Record."Info" = $group.info
    $Record."InstanceType" = $group.instancetype
    $Record."dSCorePropagationData" = $group.dSCorePropagationData
    $Record."UsnCreated" = $group.UsnCreated
    $Record."UsnChanged" = $group.UsnChanged
    $Record."WhenCreated" = $($group.Whencreated)
    $Record."WhenChanged" = $group.WhenChanged
    $Record."ManagedBy" = $group.ManagedBy
     
     
    $objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record
    $Table += $objrecord 
 
  }            
            
 $Table | Select-Object GroupName, samaccountname, WhenCreated, whenchanged, GroupType, GroupCategory, sAMAccounttype, distinguishedname, description, Info, Instancetype,  
                              dSCorePropagationData, UsnCreated, UsnChanged, ManagedBy
```

The code works until `Foreach ($Group in $Groups)...` where it has to start doing the real work. Once it gets there, it hangs and won't complete (normally finishes within 15 minutes when run on a server already on the right domain). The same domain controller and `-server` code works flawlessly for `Get-ADUser`. Is there something that's causing the hang-up, or is it just a network performance issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that is definitely slowing this down on larger data sets is the act of creating a fixed size array `$table = @()` and then creating a new one each time you do `+=` taking the contents of the previous one and adding to the current item. Then at the end the entire result is being recreated with a `Select-Object` call and is completely unnecessary. This entire script can be simplified to this.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$DC = Get-ADDomainController -DomainName silverstar.local -Discover -NextClosestSite

$props = @{
    Server     = $DC.HostName[0]

    Properties = @(
        'name',
        'samaccountname',
        'distinguishedname',
        'sAMAccounttype',
        'description',
        'GroupType',
        'GroupCategory',
        'Info',
        'Instancetype',
        'dSCorePropagationData',
        'UsnCreated',
        'UsnChanged',
        'WhenCreated',
        'whenchanged',
        'ManagedBy'
    )

    Filter      = '*'
}

$Table = Foreach ($Group in Get-AdGroup @props){
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        GroupName             = $Group.name
        SamAccountName        = $Group.samaccountname
        WhenCreated           = $group.Whencreated
        WhenChanged           = $Group.WhenChanged
        GroupType             = $Group.grouptype
        GroupCategory         = $Group.GroupCategory
        sAMAccounttype        = $Group.sAMAccountType
        DistinguishedName     = $Group.distinguishedName
        Description           = $Group.description
        Info                  = $Group.info
        Instancetype          = $Group.instancetype
        dSCorePropagationData = $Group.dSCorePropagationData
        UsnCreated            = $Group.UsnCreated
        UsnChanged            = $Group.UsnChanged
        ManagedBy             = $Group.ManagedBy
    }
}

$Table
```

If you'd like to see the groups as it's progressing, you could change it from a foreach statement to a Foreach-Object loop. The former is usually quicker because it's all in memory.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$DC = Get-ADDomainController -DomainName silverstar.local -Discover -NextClosestSite

$props = @{
    Server     = $DC.HostName[0]

    Properties = @(
        'name',
        'samaccountname',
        'distinguishedname',
        'sAMAccounttype',
        'description',
        'GroupType',
        'GroupCategory',
        'Info',
        'Instancetype',
        'dSCorePropagationData',
        'UsnCreated',
        'UsnChanged',
        'WhenCreated',
        'whenchanged',
        'ManagedBy'
    )

    Filter      = '*'
}

Get-AdGroup @props | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        GroupName             = $_.name
        SamAccountName        = $_.samaccountname
        WhenCreated           = $_.Whencreated
        WhenChanged           = $_.WhenChanged
        GroupType             = $_.grouptype
        GroupCategory         = $_.GroupCategory
        sAMAccounttype        = $_.sAMAccountType
        DistinguishedName     = $_.distinguishedName
        Description           = $_.description
        Info                  = $_.info
        Instancetype          = $_.instancetype
        dSCorePropagationData = $_.dSCorePropagationData
        UsnCreated            = $_.UsnCreated
        UsnChanged            = $_.UsnChanged
        ManagedBy             = $_.ManagedBy
    }
} -OutVariable Table
```

This will allow you to see it while also collecting the output in `$Table`. It will slow it down so I definitely recommend capturing it all to a variable in either format. For the second example just remove `-OutVariable Table` and place `$Table =`  in front of `Get-AdGroup ...`